# Chrome extension publishing delays

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I published a new version of my Chrome extension on the 29th of October, and the publishing process is still pending since (17 days). I tried to cancel and republish, I even wrote to the Google dev team, but nothing changed.

Most of the time, publishing takes a few hours only, but on a few occasions I had to wait between 3 and 10 days to get the update approved.

But more than 17 days now seems absolutely crazy. I don't know how I can provide a reliable experience for my users with such random and long delays (what if there's a bug I need to fix?).

Does anyone know why this process takes sometimes long? Is there anything I can do to change that? How do other extensions handle these delays?

Comment: Hi Julien, did you resolve this issue? Could you please share details?

Comment: Hey Iana, I didn't really find any solution I'm afraid. The review delay just seems very random and we have to deal with it. Sorry I can't help on that!